# What is the large painting in the background from the meeting with Santino and how does it relate to the scene?

Tags: john-wick-chapter-2

When John meets with Santino in the museum to accept the marker in *John Wick: Chapter 2*, what is the large painting Santino is looking at when he enters and how does it relate to the scene?  It features soldiers in a battle, a cannon, and a soldier on horseback.  I want to guess it is a French battle scene, but I have no idea if that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean this one?

[image: The painting as seen in John Wick 2]

It's [Giovanni Fattori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Fattori)'s 'La Battaglia di Custoza' or '[The Battle of Custoza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Custoza_(1866))', painted in 1880. It's on view in the [Galleria Nazionale d'Arte Moderna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galleria_Nazionale_d%27Arte_Moderna), in Rome, Italy.

[image: Fattori's La Battaglia di Custoza, 1880]